# How to get the path to the current template in Joomla 1.5?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5

I'm writing a component and would like to insert images from the template folder.

How do you get the correct path to the template folder?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

IIRC, the $mainframe global object is eventually going away. Here is a way to do it through the framework:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$templateDir = JURI::base() . 'templates/' . $app->getTemplate();
```

Comment: and how do you get the administrator template?

Answer (score 6):

What kind of path...
On filesystem:

```
$templateDir = JPATH_THEMES.DS.JFactory::getApplication()->getTemplate().DS;
```

Answer (score 3):

I've figured out one method. Use the global $mainframe object.

```
$templateDir = $mainframe->getBasePath() . "templates/" . $mainframe->getTemplate();
```

Is there another (better) way?

Comment: Looks to me as if this is the best way.